# How to style text in navigation bar in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am attempting to style the navigation bar text with the code below, but am not able to get it to work. I had code in here earlier but Xcode kept telling me that it was deprecated for iOS 7. Any advice on how to get this to work?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

    //SET COLORS AND FONTS
    UIColor* mainColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:28.0/255 green:158.0/255 blue:121.0/255 alpha:1.0f];
    UIColor* darkColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:7.0/255 green:61.0/255 blue:48.0/255 alpha:1.0f];

    NSString* fontName = @"Avenir-Book";
    NSString* boldFontName = @"Avenir-Black";

    //[self styleNavigationBarWithFontName:boldFontName];

    self.title = @"Walk With Me";

    UINavigationBar* navAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearance];

    [navAppearance setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           [UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                           [UIFont fontWithName:boldFontName size:18.0f], NSFontAttributeName,
                                           [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)], NSShadowAttributeName,
                                           nil]];
}
```

Comment: You have use the wrong order of keys and values, so it is not working.

Comment: TRY WITH THIS : NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:20.0],UITextAttributeFont,  nil];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];

Comment: @DhavalBhadania: when I try this, I get an error saying that they are deprecated...

Comment: @sharataka it's working perfect in ios 7 in my app

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code snippets for `altering the font style` of the navigation bar title -

```
NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8];
test.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                       shadow, NSShadowAttributeName,
                                                       [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" size:21.0], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
```

**Use Image as Navigation Bar Title**

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"self.png"]];
```

Comment: Nothing happens to the text color when I include this either :(.

Comment: @sharataka please check here  http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Comment: It's working but not on the current view controller.  It's working for other view controllers. Any idea how I can correct this?

Comment: @sharataka please check the link, i've sent u, there will be some thing minor u r missing, please check it out. I hope it will work. It does work for me..

Answer (score 0):

```
     NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes=@{                                          
                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor],                                                                                                  

    NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0],};

 UINavigationController * objView=(UINavigationController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;    
    objView.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleTextAttributes;
```

Comment: I included this and the text still isn't red :(

Comment: it will not work for the samecontroller you have to set in the rootviewcontroller after this it will work

Comment: UINavigationController * objView=(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    //self.title=@"Settings";
    
    objView.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleTextAttributes;

Comment: @sharataka check my updated answer i hope it will work

Comment: You're right. When I put this in, it works for other view controllers...just not the one I'm currently on. How do I put it in rootViewController? Where do I put the code in your above comment?

Comment: You can do in two way. 1. When you Set Your RootViewController. 2. Find the RootViewController using KeyWindow and set attribute to this RootViewcontroller